# Java [Android] [Spring] -Deserialize a byte array

Tags: java, android

So basically im working on an android app and i have a back-end server. I send the server a byte array, and it stores it in the database. I'm using Spring, so the Entity where the byte array is stored is this:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String username;
    private String password;

    private String name;
    private String lastName;

    private int age;

    @Lob
    private byte[] imageBytes;
}
```

When the server receives the byte array, it receives and stores something like this : `[-1, -40, -1, .....]`

Now when sending it back, i put it inside a UserDto object as so:

```
public class UserDto {
    String username;
    String password;

    String name;
    String lastName;

    int age;

    String location;

    Long id;

    byte [] imageBytes;
}
```

---

```
UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
        userDto.setImageBytes(applicationUser.getImageBytes());
        return userDto;
```

On my android app, im expecting it the call to return a ImageBytesResponse, as so:

```
public class ImageBytesResponse {
    byte[] imageBytes;

    public byte[] getImageBytes() {
        return imageBytes;
    }

    public void setImageBytes(byte[] imageBytes) {
        this.imageBytes = imageBytes;
    }
}
```

The call method :  `Call<ImageBytesResponse> getImageBytes`
However when making the call, when it returns to the android app, i get a

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 110 path $.imageBytes
```

So basicily, why does going from UserDto --> ImageByteResponse not work?
Why is it not deserilizing properly? Is the fact that my entity attribute is a @Lob a problem ?

Comment: The message says that the JSON contained a `string` (ie. "blabla") instead of the expected array at that position.  Perhaps you should check what is actually being given to you (ie, print out the JSON you're trying to decode).